# How to know when SSL certificates are expires for iOS push notification by PHP

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate

Have a good day! I implemented a push notification script on PHP for an iOS App. The push was delivered to the registered users of APP properly. But suddenly the push doesn't blasted to the devices in which my app installed. When I searched for the reason, I found that the SSL certificates for push notification has been expired.

Can anybody know to find the lifetime of SSL certificate of iOS app by using php or how can we find whether certificate is active or expired by using php

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the lifetime of the certificates in your KeyChain, and on Apple's Developer portal.

[image: keychain]

[image: dev portal]

I'm not sure which PHP library you're using for the push notifications, but chances are that it throws an exception or error message which you can catch / log.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check with my APP developer and try to throw an exceptions or error messages